# How to get exception information when calling JSON web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

In .NET 3.5, I had the following code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://kitchenpc.com/schemas/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class KitchenPC : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
   [WebMethod]
   public LogonResult Logon(string username, string password)
   {
      //If username and password are not valid...
      throw new InvalidUsernameOrPasswordException();
   }
}
```

When I would call it, if I passed in an invalid username and password, the `InvalidUsernameOrPasswordException` would be thrown and I could catch the exception in Javascript by looking at `error.get_exceptionType()`.  This is because the web service would serialize the exception info in JSON.

However, once I upgraded to .NET 4.5, this broke.  Now, when I pass in an invalid username and password, I get the HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
jsonerror: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2012 22:42:33 GMT
Content-Length: 91

{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

Basically, the exception type is lost and replaced with a generic error message.

What caused this behavior to change, and is there still a way to return exception information in JSON?  Pretty much my entire API is designed to rely on this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, this was a stupid issue.  The exception information only appears if you have:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

In your web.config (under `<system.web>`).  I'm actually not sure if this is a .NET 3.5 -> .NET 4.5 change in behavior, or if it got broke when I was re-writing my web.config build process using web.config transforms.

Does anyone know if there's a way to control this on a per web-service level?  I'd rather not show full debug info on normal page requests.

**Update:**

I also came to the conclusion that throwing exceptions to communicate error information from a web service is really not a good design.  In fact, I wrote a [post on the subject](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/11/26/without-exception/) on my blog for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

The exception types are not serializable. Use FaultException instead.

```
throw new FaultException(..);
```

Comment: True. Sorry, I didn't noticed that it those are not WCFs. :)

Comment: Yea, one of these days I need to switch over to WCF..  It's a lot more powerful.  I just needed this fixed now though.