# HttpModule doesn't capture ThreadAbortException from WebMethod (aspx or asmx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule, webmethod

I have an HTTPModule:

```
public class MyErrorModule : IHttpModule
{
  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.Error += new EventHandler(Application_Error);
  }

  public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

It is declared (IIS7.5 Integrated) in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <!-- some more stuff -->
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="ApplicationErrorModule" preCondition="" type="xxxxx"/>
  </modules>
  <!-- some more stuff -->
</system.webServer>
```

I tried without the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` too

I have a WebMethod in a normal webs.aspx.cs (it is part of a big project and I hope I don't have to move everything in an asmx...):

```
[WebMethod]
public static Model.Response GetDetails(string email)
{
  // Do some stuff and return JSON data
}
```

I call using JQuery and AJAX to POST

```
https://servername/webs.aspx/GetDetails
```

In normal situation (without unhandled Exception) things are fine, web-service return what I need. But there are cases I need to call code in a DLL that can do a

```
Context.Redirect(page,true);
```

which generates a ThreadAbortException

I was hoping that the HttpModule would help but when the THreadAbortException occurs it doesn't go in the module.

I followed some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546429/how-to-get-exception-information-when-calling-json-web-service) to use

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

but it doesn't help.

Where is it caught by ASP.Net? I am using 4.0. How can I capture the exception in the Handler?

I see a `jsonerror=true` in the HTTP Response Header, which makes me thing there is another place it is caught. I don't see other custom module that would catch the exception.

**UPDATE**

I tried with a `webs.asmx` webservice with proper annotation (ScriptService etc...) and I still can't capture the ThreadAbortException