# NSURLSession post request not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I'm trying to access my post web service through `NSURLSession` but it returns error 405 i.e (Method) not found. But it works fine when I access it through `NSURLConnection`. Below is the code.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"web service url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];



[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"en", @"language",
                         nil];

NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSLog(@"%@",mapData);

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)error.code);

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: Please add details of error.

Comment: error description ??

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in your code:

```
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Comment: Please past the 401 description.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; f
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Method not allowed.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Your service is in XML?

Comment: 401 is this reponse code not the error code. And this is this the response i get.

Comment: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: No it returns json when executed successfully.

Comment: It might be problem in PHP side.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546429/how-to-get-exception-information-when-calling-json-web-service

Comment: It run successfully when i try it with NSURLConnection. So i believe it's something with NSURLSession.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117078/discussion-between-ekta-makadiya-and-uzair-shahzad).